# Use of "that" and the verb in infinitive in this sentence

Tags: prepositions, infinitives, that

I have a doubt regarding the use of "that" in the following sentence. I also do not know the tense or kind of sentence is this.
"To verify that the following names are shown in this list:"

Answer (score 2):

This is a fragment of a sentence, a phrase.  Its meaning depends on the context of the missing words.  For example:

*"To verify that the following names are shown in this list, I will have to study the list carefully."*

It is the missing words that define the tense, not the fragment.

The word *"that"* is just part of the verbal phrase in the infinitive.

Comment: Exactly. The infinitive phrase starting with _to_ could be the subject or object complement of a verb, for instance: _I was told to verify that the following names are shown in this list; To verify that the following names are shown in this list is our goal ~ It is our goal to verify that the following names are shown in this list._